# Proving Logical Equivalence With Basic Laws of Logic

Tags: logic

I have to prove the following equivalence:

$(X \rightarrow (Y \lor Z)) \lor (X \leftrightarrow (Y \land Z)) \equiv \neg(X \land \neg Y \land \neg Z)$

This is how far I've come:

$\equiv (\neg X \lor (Y \lor Z)) \lor (X \leftrightarrow (Y \land Z))$

$\equiv (\neg X \lor (Y \lor Z)) \lor ((X \rightarrow (Y \land Z)) \land ((Y \land Z) \rightarrow X) )$
$\equiv (\neg X \lor (Y \lor Z)) \lor ((\neg X \lor (Y \land Z)) \land (\neg (Y \land Z) \lor X) )$
$\equiv (\neg X \lor (Y \lor Z)) \lor ((\neg X \lor (Y \land Z)) \land (X \lor \neg (Y \land Z)))$
$\equiv \neg [\neg(\neg X \lor (Y \lor Z)) \land \neg((\neg X \lor (Y \land Z)) \land (X \lor \neg (Y \land Z)))]$ 
$\equiv \neg[( X \land (\neg Y \land \neg Z)) \land \neg((\neg X \lor (Y \land Z)) \land (X \lor \neg (Y \land Z)))]$ 
$\equiv \neg[(X \land (\neg Y \land \neg Z)) \land (\neg(\neg X \lor (Y \land Z)) \lor \neg(X \lor \neg (Y \land Z)))]$ 
$\equiv \neg[(X \land ( \neg Y \land \neg Z)) \land ((X \land \neg(Y \land Z)) \lor \neg(X \land \neg (Y \land Z))]$ 
$\equiv \neg[(X \land (\neg Y \land \neg Z)) \land ((X \land \neg(Y \land Z)) \lor (\neg X \land (Y \land Z)))]$

Comment: Do you require a solution using laaws of logic? Because there are only 3 variables here, so you could just draw a truth table.

Comment: I don't know for sure, because we have always solved it this way. But you are right, a truth table would be way easier.